# Excel Formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

can anyone advise if this can be done.

My query is in 2 parts.

1. What I am wanting to do (simplified) is for example, have a row with 4 different columns. Let's go for Columns B,C,D and E. Column A will be used for a Name.

Now, I will call the Columns Option 1, Option 2 and Option 3 for B,C and D. Column E will be called Renewal Date.

In my example, I want to add these amount of years:
Option 1 = add 1 Year
Option 2 = add 2 years
Option 3 = add 3 years

Is it possible to have Column E (Renewal Date) to have a formula that detects which of Columns B,C or D have been completed and then add the relevant amount of years?

I.E. If I add 01/01/2017 to Column C - it will then add 01/01/2019 into Column E?

So, I guess what I am looking for is something along the lines of:
If date added to Column B, add 1 year.
If date added to Column C, add 2 years.
If date added to Column D, add 3 years.

Or as an alternative, could I add seperate formulas to Columns B,C and D and then have some way of scraping that into Column E?

2. Once I have the renewal dates in Column E, I want to be able to colour code them as follows: 
   If renewal date due - colour red.
   If renewal date due within 1 Month - colour Orange.
   If renewal date is due more than 1 Month - colour Green.

If anyone can help with this, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Chris.

Comment: Consider splitting off question 2 to a separate question.  Super User's purpose is a knowledge base of solutions to help other people with a similar problem.  It is much more effective if each question is a single problem.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying @Gary's Student answer

I'm suggesting you to change to more efficient format

```
Name | DateStart  | YearOption | DateRenewal
John | 2017-04-15 | 2          | 2019-04-15
```

YearOption column can be [a drop down list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-dropdown-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b) with 1, 2, 3 options.

Then on DateRenewal column you can use this formula

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1)+C1,MONTH(B1),DAY(B1))
```

---

Using [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), you can tell if the renewal date is approaching.

Put this formula to the Custom conditional formatting

```
=DATEDIF(D1,TODAY(),"d")>30
```

and put the green format.

```
=AND(DATEDIF(D1,TODAY(),"d")<=30, DATEDIF(D1,TODAY(),"d")>0)
```

and put the orange format.

```
=DATEDIF(D1,TODAY(),"d")=0
```

and put the red format.

Note: this treat one month as 30 days.

More about `DATEDIF` [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Honestly I've just stumbled into `DATEDIF` today when I was writing this answer :)

Comment: I like the last solution better. Don't want people to be confused looking for what's wrong when putting the conditions in wrong order :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:
In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(B1<>"",DATE(YEAR(B1)+1,MONTH(B1),DAY(B1)),IF(C1<>"",DATE(YEAR(C1)+2,MONTH(C1),DAY(C1)),IF(D1<>"",DATE(YEAR(D1)+3,MONTH(D1),DAY(D1)),"")))
```